# Open same page with different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on bookstore website. The main page has all the books. Each has it's own button. Every book has it's button linked to the same page (buy.html), I want change content by clicking on different buttons as every book has it's own description

[image]

This is my HTML button code

```
<button onclick="window.open('buy.html')" class="book4">Buy</button>
```

I need to open buy.html but with different content according to the book
but what happens now is All buttons show the same content

[image]

Can any one help me in this issue, 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question as it stands is too broad. Which part specifically are you struggling with? In general terms, you need to use a database to store the information about each book, then you pass the id of the book in the URL and read that information out of the DB and display it in the page.

Comment: Hi Norhan, welcome to SO. Please visit the how to ask page of SO, in order to make is easier for us to understand your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
From your question I could only tell you are having a problem making a dynamic website and there are dozen of approaches to tackle this problem. This cannot be achieved by looking into plain HTML (front-end). You might want to dive into back-end as well.

Comment: The buy.html page has all content of all books, how show only the content that related to the book that i click on

Comment: You are looking for a way to do this client side (which I would not recommend, because it will result in bad practice). What you could do is dive into JavaScript and the use of id-selectors: `document.getElementById("demo");` (source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) Please provide us with any code you are having difficulty with.

Comment: You could use PHP's  `$_GET` for that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php but since you haven't tagged you question with PHP, I'm not sure if this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is rather broad, I think I get your problem.
You need a way to distinguish between books without creating a new page for every book.
There are multiple ways of doing this. Personally I'd recommend using Server-Side scripts for this but you can also do this with JavaScript, you just have to put it in the link.

An example could be this:

```
<button onclick="window.open('buy.html?book=4')" class="book4">Buy</button>
```

What this does is open `buy.html` and specify what book you want to buy so you can create a function to pull only that description out of the database or however you want to do it.

I strongly recommend a database because as soon as you have a hundred or so books your page will get really slow and it's a waste of resources if you only display one.

The best way to get data out of a URL (as far as I know) is like [so](http://burnignorance.com/javascript-performance-tips/how-to-fetch-get-request-data-from-url-on-page-load-using-javascript/)

Though, next time please post your code too, that would make it a lot easier to pinpoint the problem.

Good luck.

Edit: The JavaScript that I linked was not the best solution and rather complicated so I think a better and more easily understandable function can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Comment: Could You explain more your JavaScript solution, please ?

Comment: Well basically the info page is like an employee of the book store, it knows about the books but in order to give you the right information you need to tell them what book you want to know about.

The way we do that here is by directing you to `buy.html` and adding some additional info in the URL.
The JavaScript on the page can then extract that data, like the book ID, and then use that to do a lookup in a database for the additional info or something.